# when i'm creating a array, it showing as null

Tags: c#, arrays

I am currently trying to make monolopy as a little project.
I am trying to create an Array of Tiles however when i run the code i get a nullreferenceException because Tile[] Tiles is showing as null. Any advice would be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Monolopy
{
class Board
{
     public Tile[] Tiles { get; }
     GoTile tile1;
     BuildingTile tile2;
     JailTile tile3;
     BuildingTile tile4;
     BuildingTile tile5;
     BuildingTile tile6;
     GoToJailTile tile7;
     BuildingTile tile8;
     BuildingTile tile9;
     ChanceTile tile10;
     BuildingTile tile11;
     BuildingTile tile12;



    public Board()
    {
        Tile[] Tiles = {
            tile1 = new GoTile(),
            tile2 = new BuildingTile(2, "Old Kent Road", 20, 200),
            tile3 = new JailTile(),
            tile4 = new BuildingTile(4, "WhiteHall", 40, 400),
            tile5 = new BuildingTile(5, "Euston Road", 50, 500),
            tile6 = new BuildingTile(6, "bow Street", 60, 600),
            tile7 = new GoToJailTile(),
            tile8 = new BuildingTile(8, "Strand", 70, 700),
            tile9 = new BuildingTile(9, "Fleet Street", 80, 800),
            tile10 = new ChanceTile(),
            tile11 = new BuildingTile(11, "Park Lane", 90, 900),
            tile12 = new BuildingTile(12, "Mayfair", 100, 1000)
        };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the `Tile[]` before Tiles, in your constructor, as you are populating your local variable

Comment: You define a second `Tiles` which only lives for the duration of the Board constructor. Remove the `Tile[]` from your board constructor to use the tile property instead.

Answer (score 1):

You’re redeclaring Tiles in your constructor, so the instance property is never set. Just omit the Tile[] type in your constructor.

Also, add a (private) setter to the property.

Answer (score 0):

The Tile array in constructor is **local** variable in the constructor and so any code that uses property **Tiles** of the class **Board** will get null. The member **Tiles** is actually never initialized.

Try assigning the local variable's value to your property.